# How reliable is Chrome's mobile emulation?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-chrome

I have this issue where -- seemingly only sometimes --- [jquery-embedly](https://github.com/embedly/embedly-jquery) messes up [iScroll](http://iscrolljs.com/) under Chrome's mobile emulation (works fine if I disable touch emulation, or mobile emulation altogether):

http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/nRrB5/

A lot of Android users I've asked are able to scroll just fine on their native devices -- could it then be that this is due to faulty mobile emulation in Chrome? And, if so, does anybody know what it is that makes it panic?

```
$(document).on('pagecontainershow', function () {

    // ISCROLL

    $('[data-iscroll]').each(function () {
        $(this).wrapInner("<div class='scroller'></div>")
            .wrapInner("<div class='scroller_wrapper'></div>");

        var wrapper = $(this).find('.scroller_wrapper').first(),
            windowHeight = $(window).height();

        wrapper.height(windowHeight);

        var scrollerTest = new IScroll(wrapper.get(0), {
            eventPassthrough: false,
            scrollX: false,
            scrollY: true,
            preventDefault: false,
            scrollbars: true
        });


        scrollerTest.on('scrollEnd', function () {
            // For Android users to see whether it's iScroll or their native scroller
            $('.ui-page').css('background', '#ccc')
        });
    });

    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false);


    // EMBEDLY
    var element = $('a');

    element.embedly({
        key: '',
        query: {
            maxwidth: 400,
            autoplay: true
        },
        display: function (data) {
            if (data.thumbnail_url) {
                element.html('<img src="' + data.thumbnail_url + '" />');
            }
        }
    }).on('click', function () {
        var data = $(this).data('embedly');
        $(this).replaceWith(data.html);

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: mobile emulator can't be never compared to real device browser, they are implemented in different OS and you can't be never sure about the results.

Comment: Are you able to confirm that this is indeed Chrome's mobile emulator's fault?

Comment: not reliable at all

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't in the client emulator in this example but in the code.

embedly will load content after iscroll is initialized so the iscroll plugin fail to retrive the right height.

Badly embedly plugin seems to not have a callback function (at least i don't find it) that say when it have finish to load the content.

So i edit your script removed the height set and insert a manual timeout to load iscroll.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('[data-iscroll]').each(function () {
  ...
},1000);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gasp10/nRrB5/9/)

On device it works right because they use the normal browser scrollbar (as the user use the roll on the mouse) and not the fake iscroll bar (at least they use it until it finish the scroll than pass to the normal scroll) that the emulator use with touch event, this is an example that browser emulating can't be the same as mobile browser ^^.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for trying, but I'm afraid that still doesn't work. Have you tried emulating say the Google Nexus 10 in Chrome and then visiting http://jsfiddle.net/gasp10/nRrB5/9/show? Embedly actually does have a callback function (`done`) in which I tried to refresh iScroll but that made no difference.

Comment: Take out the Embedly code and iScroll works fine under mobile emulation.

Comment: I believe the height on `.scroller_wrapper` is needed. iScroll should automatically update height on `.scroller` after load or `scrollerTest.refresh()`.

Comment: Yes i have test it on varous chrome emulattion but i don't see the error.
The possibility is that i don't uderstand the real error that you have, but if i understand right on mobile in you example the iscroll stop at half of the real total scroll

Comment: The problem is that in Chrome emulation it is impossible to scroll the iScroll scroller after `embedly()` has been executed. Note that there's also a Chrome scroller which can be clicked and dragged down, but that is to be ignored.

Comment: Note that the background will turn grey on scroll end for the iScroll scroller - just to confirm the right scroller has been scrolled.